# Delete directory Gulp 4

Tags: asynchronous, gulp, del, gulp-clean

For some reason when I run the clean function it works on its own but when it is a series it is unable to work.

Here is my function

```
async function clean(cb) {
    await del('./_temp', { force : true });
    cb();
}
```

Here is my error

```
[13:38:45] Plumber found unhandled error:
 Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat
```

Comment: If I make a series in the package.json it works fine : S
"dev": "gulp && gulp clean"

Comment: It is working fine in my current gulp file.
check your gulp version and Try  del('./_temp/**', { force : true });
it will delete everything in this folder